# How to handle IndexError exception before combining objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

**What I'm looking to achieve:**

The code added below filters through a parsed HTML page looking for specific values. Each specific value is then added to its own specific list in the form of a dictionary. Once all the values are added to the lists the dictionaries within are then combined into a JSON blob that I can then export.

Note - This is part of a quick PoC, so it was written quick and dirty. Forgive me.

**My problem:**

When the following lists dictionaries are combined I do not encounter any issues when export the blob:

- jobs
- names
- dates
- summaries

However, when the locations list is added in order to be combined into the blob an IndexError exception is encountered. As shown in the image below:

[IndexError Encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjHzT.png)

**My Analysis:**

I've found that sometimes the value is not found because it was not included in the parsed HTML for reason/s that I cannot control, ie. it was not added my the user when it was created. The issue in this case being that the len of the locations list being 14 whilst the len of the other lists being equal at 15 which is causing the IndexError exception when I combine the lists using a for loop.

**My Question:**

As shown in my code below, I'm trying to handle the issue by assigning a placeholder value, "null", when the scraped value is not found but for some reason the value is not applied and I still encounter the IndexError exception. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

**My Code:**

```
import ast
import sys

# Create empty lists [Global]
jobs = []
names = []
dates = []
summaries = []
locations = []

# Function - Ingest parsed HTML data | Filter out required values
def getJobs(parsedHTML):

    # Loop - Get job title
    for div in parsedHTML.find_all(name='h2', attrs={'class':'title'}):
        for a in div.find_all(name='a', attrs={'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
            val = str(a.getText().strip())
            if val is None:
                locations.append({"job-title": "null"})
            else:
                dictItem = {"job-title": f"{val}"}
                jobs.append(dictItem)
            

    # Loop - Get job poster's name
    for div in parsedHTML.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'sjcl'}):
        for span in div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'company'}):
            val = str(span.getText().strip())
            if val is None:
                locations.append({"company-name": "null"})
            else:
                dictItem = {"company-name": f"{val}"}
                names.append(dictItem)

    # Loop - Get the date the job post was created
    for div in parsedHTML.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'result-link-bar'}):
        for span in div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'date date-a11y'}):
            val = str(span.getText().strip())
            if val is None:
                locations.append({"date-created": "null"})
            else:
                dictItem = {"date-created": f"{val}"}
                dates.append(dictItem)

    # Loop - Get short job description
    for divParent in parsedHTML.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'result'}):
        for divChild in divParent.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'summary'}):
            val = str(divChild.getText().strip())
            if val is None:
                locations.append({"short-description": "null"})
            else:
                dictItem = {"short-description": f"{val}"}
                summaries.append(dictItem)

    # Loop - Get job location
    for div in parsedHTML.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'sjcl'}):
        for span in div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'location'}):
            val = str(span.getText().strip())
            if val is None:
                locations.append({"location": "null"})
            else:
                dictItem = {"location": f"{val}"}
                locations.append(dictItem)

    
# Function - Generate test data
def testData(parsedHTML, typeProc):

    # typeProc == True | Export data to text files
    if typeProc:
        #getJobs(parsedHTML)

        with open("jobs.txt", "w") as file:
            for line in jobs:
                file.write(str(line))
                file.write("\n")
            file.close()
        
        with open("names.txt", "w") as file:
            for line in names:
                file.write(str(line))
                file.write("\n")
            file.close()
        
        with open("dates.txt", "w") as file:
            for line in dates:
                file.write(str(line))
                file.write("\n")
            file.close()
        
        with open("summaries.txt", "w") as file:
            for line in summaries:
                file.write(str(line))
                file.write("\n")
            file.close()
        
        with open("locations.txt", "w") as file:
            for line in locations:
                file.write(str(line))
                file.write("\n")
            file.close()
    
    # typeProc == False | Import data from txt files, convert to dictionary and append to list
    elif typeProc == False:
        with open("jobs.txt", "r") as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            for i in range(len(content)):
                content[i] = content[i].replace("\n", "")
                content[i] = ast.literal_eval(content[i])
                jobs.append(content[i])
            file.close()

        with open("names.txt", "r") as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            for i in range(len(content)):
                content[i] = content[i].replace("\n", "")
                content[i] = ast.literal_eval(content[i])
                names.append(content[i])
            file.close()

        with open("dates.txt", "r") as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            for i in range(len(content)):
                content[i] = content[i].replace("\n", "")
                content[i] = ast.literal_eval(content[i])
                dates.append(content[i])
            file.close()

        with open("summaries.txt", "r") as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            for i in range(len(content)):
                content[i] = content[i].replace("\n", "")
                content[i] = ast.literal_eval(content[i])
                summaries.append(content[i])
            file.close()

        with open("locations.txt", "r") as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            for i in range(len(content)):
                content[i] = content[i].replace("\n", "")
                content[i] = ast.literal_eval(content[i])
                locations.append(content[i])
            file.close()

    # Else | If this else is hit, something is greatly fvcked
    else:
        print("Function: testData | Error: if statement else output")
        sys.exit(1)

# Function - Remove items from all lists
def wipeLists():
    jobs.clear()
    names.clear()
    dates.clear()
    summaries.clear()
    locations.clear()

# Function - JSON Blob Generator
def genJSON(parsedHTML):
    # Testing with cached local IRL data
    #testData(parsedHTML, False)

    getJobs(parsedHTML)
    jsonBlob = []
    
    # Merge dictionaries | Combining dictionaries into single object + Append to jsonBlob list
    for i in range(len(jobs)):
        sumObj = {**jobs[i], **names[i], **dates[i], **summaries[i], **locations[i]}
        #sumObj = {**jobs[i], **names[i], **dates[i], **summaries[i]}
        jsonBlob.append(sumObj)

    return jsonBlob
```

Comment: If I were you I'd be worried not about handling an error but about fixing the problem. So sometimes location is missing? Which record is it missing from? is it missing from the first record? Well then all the records will have incorrect locations populated for them. In fact, here IndexError is saving you from making a mess.

Comment: The "null" placeholder will fail when there's no "location" item present in the record you're trying to parse.

Comment: @pavel - Issue has been resolved, thank you for your comment. I've also added my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You @pavel for your notes on how to approach the issue. I found that the value I was looking for was actually a required field when it was created and for some reason I was just not getting the correct amount of values when I was filtering the parsed data.

I reviewed the source code of the page/s again and found that there was another field with the exact value I was looking for. So now instead of getting the text of a span-element inside the parent div, I am getting the custom data-* attribute value of the parent div-element. I have not encountered a single error whilst testing.

**Updated Code:**

```
# Loop - Get job location
for div in parsedHTML.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'sjcl'}):
    for divChild in div.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'recJobLoc'}):
        dictItem = {"location": f"{divChild['data-rc-loc']}"}
        locations.append(dictItem)
```

Thank You to everyone who tried to help. This has been resolved.